# bootstrap with datetime picker is not looking+working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using the following code and it shrinks each line and also the overall UI is lost for some reason. HOw can I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
          href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
    </script>


</head>
<body>


<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">


                <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
                    <input type="text"></input>
                    <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <input id="text" placeholder="text" type="text" class="form-control"
                   required="true">
        </div>

    </div>




</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
        language: 'pt-BR'
    });
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Please add Fiddle for it and reproduce the issue there

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4kk7e77z/

Comment: The fiddle's sources are not loading.
And you have two scripts with bootstrap.min.js, maybe that is the problem

Comment: Can you help me sort it out? Which one should I remove?

Comment: I tried removing both bootstrap.min.js But the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

A lot of problems here, my friend:

1. Loading multiple versions of Bootstrap
2. Loading jQuery after at least one bootstrap `js` file
3. At least in the fiddle, loading over `http` as opposed to `https`
4. The `datetimepicker` you're trying to use is not compatible with bootstrap 3 and is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker).
5. Your html contained classes from both, old and new versions of bootstrap.

[Here's a somewhat fixed version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3ef5Lhr/), but don't expect it to actually work as you wanted it to.

Comment: Hi Serg. Can you suggest any datetime picker other than the one I am using with bootstrap ? It'll be of great help. Thanks :)

Comment: I can't recommend from personal experience but I can tell you how to choose one. Look at GitHub pages for any plugin you find and make sure nothing says that the plugin is no longer maintained. Also, when comparing two plugins look at something like the number of stars each has on github. That will show you a measure of popularity and you want to be using whatever has the bigger community. For example: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: Can you please show how can I use the same with jsfiddle. I really appreciate your help :)